# Get current position of moving/rotating element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to get current position of a rectangle shaped div. Element moves and rotates with other elements (not by itself, just attached to another rotating div).

My current code gets the current position, however it feeds wrong position when said element moves. Im using pure JS for everything.

Any idea how to make the calculations include proper position of the element? (i need to catch top-left corner only, not center)

f to get current x/y of element in question(turret), 'field' is game board (not full screen):

```
function turretPositionUpdater() {
    turretX = turret.getBoundingClientRect().left - field.offsetLeft;
    turretY = turret.getBoundingClientRect().top - field.offsetTop;
}
```

full app fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n96kaf24/  (press R to enable rotation)

Comment: for now i have a temporary fix - i nested another div inside the turret (lets say 'turret-end') and updated everything to calculate x/y from that :)